# r if statement returns number of level rather than the level text

Tags: r, if-statement, numbers, levels

I have a table like the following image and I'm trying to use a simple if statement to return the country name only in cases where food is "Oranges". The 3rd column is the desired outcome, the 4th column is what I get in R.

[image]

In excel the formula would be:

```
=IF(A2="Oranges",B2,"n/a")
```

I have used the following r code to generate the "oranges_country" variable:

```
table$oranges_country <- ifelse (Food == "Oranges", Country , "n/a")
```

[As per the image above] The code returns the number of the level (e.g. 6) in the levels list for 'Country' rather than 'Country' itself (e.g. "Spain"). I understand where this coming from (the position in the extract as below), but it's a pain particularly when using several nested if statements.

```
levels(Country)
[1] "California"  "Ecuador"     "France"      "New Zealand" "Peru"        "Spain"       "UK"
```

There must be a simple way to change this???

As requested in a comment: dput(table) output as follows:
`dput(table)
structure(list(Food = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges"), class = "factor"), 
    Country = structure(c(3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("California", 
    "Ecuador", "France", "New Zealand", "Peru", "Spain", "UK"
    ), class = "factor"), Desired_If.Outcome = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("California", 
    "n/a", "Spain"), class = "factor"), oranges_country = c("n/a", 
    "n/a", "6", "n/a", "n/a", "6", "1", "n/a", "n/a"), desiredcolumn = c(NA, 
    NA, 6L, NA, NA, 6L, 1L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Food", "Country", 
"Desired_If.Outcome", "oranges_country", "desiredcolumn"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `ifelse` loop. Firstly , change Table$Country to character()

```
 table$Country<-as.character(Table$Country)
 table$desiredcolumn<-ifelse(table$Food == "Oranges", table$Country, NA)
```

Here is my version:

```
Food<-c("Ap","Ap","Or","Ap","Ap","Or","Or","Ba","Ba")
Country<-c("Fra","UK","Sp","Nz","UK","Sp","Cal","Per","Eq")
Table<-cbind(Food,Country)
Table<-data.frame(Table)
Table$Country<-as.character(Table$Country)
Table$DC<-ifelse(Table$Food=="Or", Table$Country, NA)
Table

Food Country   DC
1   Ap     Fra <NA>
2   Ap      UK <NA>
3   Or      Sp   Sp
4   Ap      Nz <NA>
5   Ap      UK <NA>
6   Or      Sp   Sp
7   Or     Cal  Cal
8   Ba     Per <NA>
9   Ba      Eq <NA>
```

Comment: thanks Max. This is what I've been doing in my code extract above `table$oranges_country <- ifelse (Food == "Oranges", Country , "n/a")`. I've just tried your slight variant and it gives the same outcome `> desiredcolumn
[1] NA NA  6 NA NA  6  1 NA NA`

Comment: could you please post the output of table by using dput(table). If it is many rows , then just gives us the first 10 rows.

Comment: Can you please first do - `table$Country<-as.character(Table$Country)`, and then run the ifelse code.

Comment: Excellent thanks Max - works a treat. Curiously, the ifelse is very sensitive. After applying the `Table$Country<-as.character(Table$Country)`, the following ifelse doesn't work as I would like: `> table$DC <- ifelse (Food == "Oranges", Country , NA)` but your more precise one does:
`> table$DC <- ifelse (table$Food == "Oranges", table$Country , NA)`

Comment: Its the data also. R interprets it as a factor, you have to tell R to change it to character. No worries. Happy new Year. Edit: Im not sure why your code doesnt work, but one suggestion, I would always specify the column names with the dataframe name with the `$` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if your table is called `table`):

```
table[table$Food=="Oragnes", ]
```

Comment: Thanks Marta, it is indeed called table! This just returns the filtered table of just those 3 lines for related to Oranges? (not sure how to include tables in the stackoverflow comments formatting)

Comment: If you want only `Country` column for those choosen, try: `table[table$Food=="Oragnes", ]$Country`

Comment: Ahh I see. But let's say in my real example I have many columns and I'm trying to build up complex nested if statements so that I can do 'pivot' style analysis on this, so instead my r code might be something like `table$oranges_country <- ifelse (Food == "Oranges", Country , ifelse (Food == "Apples", OtherVariable1, ifelse (Food == "Bananas", OtherVariable2, OtherVariable3)))` so I think it's easiest to capture this in one column.